# If $b_n=(-1)^n+\frac{n}{2019}$, find the sum of the first $2019$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

The common term of the sequence $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,...$ is $b_n=(-1)^n+\dfrac{n}{2019},n=1,2,...$ What is the sum of the first $2019$ terms of the sequence?

I have not found a way to solve the problem, as I do not see how to find a formula for the sum of the first $n$ terms of the given sequence (as we would have if the numbers were in a.p. or g.p.).

Finding the first few elements didn't help me much even on an intuitive level: $$b_1=-\dfrac{2018}{2019},b_2=\dfrac{2021}{2019},b_3=-\dfrac{2016}{2019},b_4=\dfrac{2023}{2019},...$$

Are we supposed to find such a formula, or is there something special about the sum of the first $2019$ terms of the sequence?

Comment: Can you compute $\sum_{n=1}^{2019} (-1)^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{2019} \frac{n}{2019}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$b_k=(-1)^k+\frac{1}{2019}k$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n b_k=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k+\frac{1}{2019}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k \\ \sum_{k=1}^n b_k=\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{2019}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\ \sum_{k=1}^{2019}b_k=\frac{(-1)^{2019}-1}{2}+\frac{1}{2019}\frac{2019(2019+1)}{2} \\ =-1+\frac{2020}{2} \\ =1009.$$

Answer (score 2):

For a way to do it in your head:
Calculate $$b_1+b_{2018}$$
$$b_2+b_{2017}$$
$$...$$
$$b_{1008}+b_{1011}$$
$$b_{1009}+b_{1010}$$
Then calculate $b_{2019}$, the one missing term from the sum, and add...

(Thank you, Gauss)